# Laravel migration in different branches

Tags: laravel, database-migration

In my app, built with Laravel 5.1, I have a branch dev.

I had to implement 2 new features, so I created first branch (starting from dev) that needed 2 tables (so new migrations), then, when I finished it, I created second branch (starting to dev) and also this feature needed a different table so new migration.

So my situation is something like:

```
branch 1 -> migration1
branch 2 -> migration2, migration3
```

But now I need to change (many columns) the table related to branch1 so I should rollback migration, because I would not make new migration for change but I would rollback migration and recreate.

But my problem now is that if I return in my branch1 and try to do:

```
php artisan:migrate rollback
```

The latest migrations (on my db) are the tables for branch2 (migration2, migration3) and not the table related to branch1 (migration1).

So what is the right way for manage migration between many branch?

Comment: First rollback migrations in `branch2`, then move to `branch1` and make changes.

Comment: thankyou for answer, yes, but  I believe that way is very confusing, now it is not a problem because there is only 2 branch with only 2 features, but If I had many branch with many migration I should go in any branch and rollback one by one.

Comment: But there is no other way. Thats how git and migrations work.

Comment: ok, thankyou for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

When I create a new branch in a larger project. For example, when starting a refactor. I create a copy of the database and prefix this copy with the branch name. This saves many headaches when switching back to the current master or production branches for quick bug fixes,... This way you will never have any migration conflicts as you describe in your question.

When switching branches I update my `.env` database name and I clear the application's cache. This way Laravel starts using the database corresponding to the state your application/migrations are in.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: only `php artisan config:cache` is needed

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a copy of your database table and denote them in your `.env`  file:

```
DB_DATABASE_BRANCH=branchtable
DB_DATABASE=mastertable
```

then switch to your branch and change in `config/database.php` your database driver to `DB_DATABASE_BRANCH`

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_BRANCH', 'forge'),
```

Since `config/database.php` is tracked by git, you will automatically switch your database when using `git checkout ***`. This is better the Odyssee's solution because you do not need to touch your `.env` file whenever you switch your branch.

Checkout my [blog post](https://dr-nielsen.com/php/create-database-for-branch-and-phpunit) for more details.